# Java Robot doesnt Press Enter Key how it should

Tags: java, robotframework, enter

Im trying to program a litte Robot, that should just write for some hours the same phrase with a delay.

But somehow, if i have mor than 1 Letter at the same time before the Enter Key, it rather types a Pyramide.

For Example, if i wanna print "ted", it prints the following:

ted

tedted

tedtedted

tedtedtedted

[...]

(There is no empty line between the Pyramide-Lines)

It gets really frustrating.

I Tried many solutions, but none worked. Making a Delay for the robot, an extra Robot for the Enter Key, put it in an extra Thread or creating new Robots every time before a new Typing. It just doesnt work. What am i doing wrong?
Here is a SSCCE with some trys i did:

```
@SuppressWarnings("CallToPrintStackTrace")
public class RobotTest {

private static Robot robo;
private static Robot okRobo;

static {
    createRobos();
}

private static void createRobos(){
    try {
        robo = new Robot();
        okRobo = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings({"CallToPrintStackTrace", "SleepWhileInLoop"})
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        createRobos();
        perform();
//            Thread.sleep(500);
        performOk();
    }
}

private static void perform() {
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
//        robo.waitForIdle();
}

private static void performOk() {
    okRobo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    okRobo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
//        okRobo.waitForIdle();
}
```

}

And here is my first try, that should work in my opinion too, but it doesnt:

```
public class RobotTest {

private static Robot robo;

@SuppressWarnings("CallToPrintStackTrace")
static {
    try {
        robo = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        perform();
    }
}

private static void perform() {
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robo.delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating new robots every time in your for loop as well as in the static initializer?

Comment: Yeah, someone on the Internet said, this might help. Before that, i had the Body of createRobos inside the static block and just initialized them once. But it didnt change anything. I even had just 1 Robo at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try not to initialize your Robot at each iteration of the loop. Call `createRobos()` outside of the loop. That is unless you have a specific reason that you're doing it that way.
2. I don't think you need two separate instances of Robot to get this to work.
3. Instead of using `Thread.sleep()`, you can use the `delay()` method within the `Robot` class. This is if you want to add a delay between `Robot` method calls.

You may want to try to add a delay between when you're typing out the letter keys and when you're pressing the enter key and after you press the enter key. A 50 - 100 ms delay will usually do the trick. Sometimes, things get a little messed up, especially when you throw `Thread.sleep()` into the mix.

I ran your code with these small changes and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Exactly that was m first attempt. But like this, it adds the Enter after the first output and all others are in the same line. The CreateRobos + the second Robot were just Answers to similar questions, that might help. If i use only one robo, with or without delay before the Enter, just the first output gets it, but no other.
For my test i let it write in Notepad++ if that can cause the problem

Comment: @Schesam I think it might just be a problem with Notepad++. I tested it out in Notepad++ and I got the result that you described. However, the code outputs the desired result in other text editors such as regular notepad or Atom. I even tried it in the Eclipse code editor and console and it worked as intended. If you're okay with not using Notepad++ then you should be fine.

Comment: Exactly what the problem was... Weird. I need it on a Webpage, i just used Notepad++ to verify, what the Robot writes. On all other Sources it works like intended. God knows, what the Problem is in Notepad++